# AES padding ambiguity

Tags: encryption, aes, padding, encryption-symmetric

I have been implementing AES in C and I am now finalising the program by implementing padding. Reading lots of other SO questions on the padding topic I have found that a popular way to do this is by filling each of the remaining places in the state with the number of places left. For example if I only had 12 bytes to encrypt, I would pad the remaining 4 bytes with 4. My question is when decrypting if I have a block which is full but ends in a 1, how do I know if this is one byte of padding or just the value 1?

DISCLAIMER: I know this program should never be used in production as it probably has all sorts of different insecurities. I am doing this for fun, not to encrypt top secret documents.

Comment: If you want to see my code it is here: https://gist.github.com/dangee1705/80b110f764914847eea33391db7ed398

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is the [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

In order to disambiguate, you always need to have padding. Additionally, the plaintext for modes like ECB or CBC mode needs to be a multiple of the block size.

Both constraints put together lead to a simple solution: you *always* add padding up to the *next* multiple of the block size. If the plaintext is already a multiple of the block size, then you add a full block of padding where each byte represents 16 (for AES).

Comment: thank you i didn't see that part of the page for some reason